# gnu parallel pair argument with file input arguments

Tags: linux, gnu-parallel

I have a file with many lines, and on each line I have the arguments I want to pass to parallel with a tab separator.

I run this script

```
cat $hdd_file | grep $ssd | parallel -C '\t' clean_and_destroy
```

And it works, $hdd_file is the filename, the grep collects the lines which hdds have a certain $ssd as a cache, and then the parallel calls a function which destroys their connection.

Now that I made new partitions to the cleaned ssds, I try to call parallel like this:

```
cat $hdd_file | grep $ssd | parallel -C '\t' create_new_cache :::+ `seq $partitions_per_ssd`
```

Which should get the arguments from the pipe and pair them with the numbers given, but it does not.

```
cat $hdd_file | grep $ssd | parallel -C '\t' create_new_cache ::: {} :::+ `seq $partitions_per_ssd`
```

I also tried this and it still doesn't work. The {} :::+ are passed as arguments for some reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU **`parallel`** solution:

Sample `input.txt` (for demonstration):

```
a   b
c   d
e   f
```

---

`grep '^[ac]' input.txt` will be used to emulate command(or pipeline) acting like input source file

---

```
parallel -C '\t' echo :::: <(grep '^[ac]' input.txt) ::: $(seq 1 3)
```

The output:

```
a b 1
a b 2
a b 3
c d 1
c d 2
c d 3
```

---

- `:::: argfiles` - treat `argfiles` as input source. `:::` and `::::` can be mixed.

---

To aggregate elements from each input source - add `--xapply` option:

```
parallel -C '\t' --xapply echo :::: <(grep '^[ac]' input.txt) ::: $(seq 1 2)
```

The output:

```
a b 1
c d 2
```

Comment: thanks, that's a step closer to what i want. I actually want this:
`parallel -C '\t' echo :::: <(grep '^[ac]' input.txt) :::+ $(seq 1 2)`
`a b 1, c d 2`
but i get `parallel: Error: Cannot open input file `:::+': No such file or directory.`

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης, you need `--xapply` option. See my update

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης :::+ is from 20160422. You probably have an older version.

Comment: You can also use '-' as input file: `grep '^[ac]' input.txt | parallel -C '\t' echo :::: - :::+ {1..10}`

Comment: @OleTange your example doesn't work, I tried it many times with different variations, it gets the `:::+` as an argument of the function

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης What version are you using? Is `parallel --version` > 20160422.